# Command to find if new information is being written into the file

Tags: linux

hi everyone suppose i have a file which is open by a process for writing but i want to check if new information is been written into that file. Do I have any command in linux to check that or is there a sample script that will help.

Till now I have checked two commands : fuser, lsof which tells which process has opened the file for writing but they are not giving any significant o/p regarding if new information is being written into the file.

Comment: What about `tail -f` ?

Comment: But to terminate tail -f I need to interrupt using cntrl - c . I want to use it in a script and based on it I need to do some more processing. Sorry I didnt mention this before. basically my rsyslog service is writing logs into log file.

Comment: i wantto restart rsyslog service when syslog stops writing logs into my file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)

```
while inotifywait -qe modify filename
do
# some processing
done
```

or you could check if the file has been modified with [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) e.g.

```
stat -c %Y file
```